# Automatically resize column when another is hidden

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple bootstrap grid with two columns. At a certain point of my application, the first column (`#smallcolumn`) will be hidden. I want the second column to fit the entire width.

I would prefer a solution with css only if possible..

Minimal example: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/32684/

When #smallcolumn is hidden (with `ng-show="shouldShow"`), how do I make `#largecolumn` fill the entire width instead of `(9 / 12)` ? (Note : I am stuck in the scope of `whateverController`)

Comment: use `ng-class`, something like `ng-class="shouldShow ? 'col-xs-9' : 'col-xs-12'"` on the largecolumn

Comment: @Claies : Thanks but I can't get out of the scope of ng-controller="whateverController"

Comment: that doesn't really make sense.  why would a controller be only bound to a single column of a view element?

Comment: @Claies : because another one is already bound to the other column.